# Data binding in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to setup a binding between a class instance and two WPF textboxes. Still, the textboxes don't change their status and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

XAML

```
<DockPanel>
   <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource caption}">Testing System</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="txt1" Text="DC"/>
   <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="txt2"  Text="PD"/>
   <Button Height="20" Width="100" Click="clickBinding">Bind</Button>
   <Button Height="20" Width="100" Click="clickChangeBinding">Change Status</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private ADSbinding myADS = new ADSbinding();
private void clickBinding(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Binding b1, b2;

   b1 = new Binding();
   b2 = new Binding();
   b1.Source = myADS.DeviceConfigured;
   b2.Source = myADS.ProcessingData;


   b1.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
   b2.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

   BindingOperations.SetBinding(txt1, TextBlock.TextProperty, b1);
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(txt2, TextBlock.TextProperty, b2); 
   }

   private void clickChangeBinding(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      myADS.changedata();
   }
```

Class:

```
public class ADSbinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private string deviceConfigured = "false";
   private string processingData = "false";

   public ADSbinding()
   {
      ProcessingData = "true";
   }

   // Get-Set methods
   public string DeviceConfigured
   {
      get { return deviceConfigured; }
      set 
      { 
         deviceConfigured = value;
         Changed("DeviceConfigured");
      }
   }
   public string ProcessingData
   {
      get { return processingData; }
      set
      {
         processingData = value;
         Changed("ProcessingData");
      }
   }

   private void Changed(string propertyName)
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public void changedata()
   {
      DeviceConfigured = "change";
      ProcessingData = "change";
    }
}
```

When pressing "clickBinding" the status changes, when "clickChangeBinding" it remains, by clicking "clickBinding" again it changes. Its a very straight forward attempt and I can't figure out where the problem is. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the bindings, you are setting `Source` to the properties of your object, not the object itself. You should specify the property name in the `Binding` constructor, and then set the source to your object:

```
    b1 = new Binding("DeviceConfigured");
    b2 = new Binding("ProcessingData");
    b1.Source = myADS;
    b2.Source = myADS;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition of bde answer you can make also usage of an extension method that allows you to set the binding directly on the FrameworkElement

```
public static void SetBinding(this FrameworkElement target, DependencyProperty property, TargetType source, Expression<Func<TargetType, PropertyType>> property_accessor)
{
  var binding = new Binding(source.PropertyName(property_accessor));
  binding.Source = source;
  target.SetBinding(property, binding);
}


public static string PropertyName(this TargetType obj, Expression<Func> property_accessor)
 { 
return ((MemberExpression)property_accessor.Body).Member.Name; 
}
```

Instead of typing

```
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(txt1, TextBlock.TextProperty, b1);
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(txt2, TextBlock.TextProperty, b2);
```

you can use the extension method SetBinding that is definied above

```
txt1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myADS, x => x.DeviceConfigured);
txt2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myADS, x => x.ProcessingData);
```

This way you avoid passing the name of the property as as string.

Comment: Where is TargetType?